# как сделать такой редирект в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Если ссылка заканчивается на `?A` или на `?B`, то делаем 301 реирект на туже ссылку, только без этих параметров.

Например: site.ru/company/?A -> site.ru/company/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Убираем все GET-параметры после знака вопроса*

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=301,L]
```

*UPD по комменту

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^first=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: спасибо большое, а как убрать только, те, которые имеют 1 параметр из заданного набора, например на параметр `first` или `second`?

т.е. если параметры только `?first` или `?second`  тогда их убираем

Comment: Пожалуйста) - Добавил возможный вариант в ответ

Comment: спасибо, условие редиректа сразабывает, а вот сам редирект не совсем правильно: к домену сайта прибавляется путь `/var/www/vhosts/site.ru/` и до текущей страницу без get-параметров.

Comment: т.е. если было так: `https://site.ru/contacts/?first=123` ставиться так: `https://site.ru/var/www/vhosts/site.ru/contacts`

Comment: Трудно сказать, что у Вас именно - при любом раскладе не должно появляться, что Вы приводите - значит, либо идет нарушение предыдущих редиректов или настроек vhost Apache, думается.

Comment: а можно как-то принудительно собрать урл ?

Например так: site.ru/{PATH} ?

Comment: Посмотрите варианты тут http://www.seoschool.ru/search-engine-optimization-seo/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide.html#h8 и http://coderhs.com/archive/redirect_301 - думается, что все-таки надо разобраться, почему у Вас такое выходит - а то костыль на костыль не есть хорошо.